# Can i initialize a struct as a function parameter

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Let's say that i have a struct named vector2.

```
typedef struct
{
   int x, y;
} vector2;
```

And i have a function that  . Prints that vector using printf.

```
void printvector2(vector2 v)
{
   printf("x: %d", v.x);
   printf("y: %d", v.y);
}
```

I know i can initialize a struct like this,
and then put it in the function as a parameter

```
vector2 size = {800, 600};

printvector2(size);
```

But, i don't really want to make a new variable Every time i
print a vector2.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
printvector2({800, 600});
```

but it spits out an error.

#### *Please help!*

Comment: Use [*compound literals*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal): `printfvector((vector2) { 800, 600 });`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef struct
{
    int x, y;
} vector2;

void printvector2(vector2 v)
{
    printf("x: %d\n", v.x);
    printf("y: %d\n", v.y);
}

int main() {
    printvector2((vector2){800, 600});   // compound literal
    return 0;
}
```